# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.provider[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function

Tags: web3js, react, web3-providers

I am receiving the error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.provider[(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)] is not a function".

However, I have not used "this.provider" in my code. My code is provided below. Does anyone know how I could resolve this?

Help would be insanely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
this.gamechanger.setProvider(this.web3);
```

To this:

```
this.gamechanger.setProvider(this.web3.currentProvider);
```